# Laravel package to GitHub

Tags: php, git, laravel

I was following the tutorial at [this link](https://devdojo.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-package) to create a Laravel package. I have modified it and I wanted make a custom artisan command.

Command works so far, but I am planning to expand it and publish it later on. Tutorial doesn't cover how to push package to git though. I know how can I push everything up of course, but I've never did this "partial" versioning.

How can version only my `packages` folder so that I can publish it and enable for everybody to use?

Comment: Your entire repository should be the package you're trying to publish without the laravel boilerplate stuff. You can still work on it locally as you are now but only commit the files in the folder that's your actual package

Comment: Would calling `git init` inside that folder do the trick?

Comment: Yes, that should do it. Check existing package repositories and compare with what composer downloads in /vendor to get a better idea on how it's meant to look like